# Make http request call using Inline Editor in DialogFlow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Below is the function i am calling but every time i am getting below error
Error - MalformedResponse
Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response.

$ below is the complete code

```
function callExternalAPI () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       let path = 'path';
       console.log('API Request: ' + path);
       http.get({host: host, path: path}, (res) => {
       let body = ''; 
       res.on('data', (d) => { body += d; }); 
       res.on('end', () => {
         let response = JSON.parse(body);
         let output = 'response';
         console.log(output);
         resolve(output);
      });
      res.on('error', (error) => {
         console.log(`Error calling the weather API: ${error}`);
         reject();
      });
  });
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('CardView',callExternalAPI);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you are calling `callWeatherApi()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inline editor uses [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). By default, your project is using the Firebase "Spark" plan, which limits network connections to Google services only.

Since the connection is being rejected, the `if (err)` block is being triggered, and you have not specified a response to be sent back to the user when this happens, so you're getting the "empty speech response" error.

The easiest solution is to upgrade to [paid plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/), such as the "Blaze" plan, which will require you to register a credit card, but which has a free tier, so you won't be charged for a base level of operations, which generally covers your development and testing, and may even cover light production usage.

You should likely also setup a response in the event of an error.